# Optical Tweezers in a Vacuum | Oscillation

Tags: optics, photons, radiation-pressure

In the context of optical tweezers, if used in a vacuum and a particle starts off slightly to the right from the center of a beam, would the particle eventually become perfectly centered or would it continuously slingshot from right to left?

Does this depend on the strength of the laser?